# Is it right having two google analytic code on a page in magento?

Tags: magento-1.7, extensions, google-analytics

My magento site maintains the google analytic and remarketing section thorough an extension called "Aromicon (GUA)", which put a script and some parameters in every page.
 Now I have to add some code for **dynamic google remarketing** in some specific pages like Home, Category, Product, cart. So when I add another script having same function as in "GUA" but parameters are different, then will it work properly ? Or is it possible in other way ? Kindly guide..Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your Google API tracking Ids different for both scripts that should not be an issue.

But if it is same in both the GA scripts, when every time page load GA js script code will send tracking hit twice to Google analytics servers.

You can add default Magento GA code for particular pages.

**For that see below file,**

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/googleanalytics.xml
```

You will need to add below set of xml script for particular page.

```
<reference name="head" before="-">
   <block type="googleanalytics/ga" name="google_analytics" as="google_analytics" template="googleanalytics/ga.phtml" />
</reference>
```

You can do same for Google re-marketing code.

Comment: Yes @Akhilesh, Both the Ids are same. So will it create any problem ?

Comment: Yes, It will send hit to google twice and it will show pages with double tracking.

Comment: so how can I add the dynamic remarketing script in specific pages ?

Comment: I have edited my answer.

Comment: So should I modify the ga.phtml with my dynamic script ?

Comment: No. you can create new phtml for your dynamic script and call it on pages which you want. and remove ga.phtml from those pages so it will not conflict.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29803/discussion-between-kishore-patra-and-akhilesh-patel).